# How to select the sum() of a group of rows and the sum() of another group

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have created a SQLfiddle demo with sample data and desired result here :(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe73a/7)

**sample data**

```
-- table company
+--------+---------+
|   id   |   name  |
+--------+---------+
|   1    |   foo   |
|   2    |   bar   |
+--------+---------+

 -- table sales
+--------+---------------+-----------------+
|   id   |   company_id  |   total_amount  |
+--------+---------------+-----------------+
|   1    |       1       |      300.0      |
|   2    |       1       |      300.0      |
|   2    |       1       |      100.0      |
+--------+---------------+-----------------+

 -- table moves
+--------+---------------+-----------------+
|   id   |   company_id  |   balance_move  |
+--------+---------------+-----------------+
|   1    |       1       |      700.0      |
|   2    |       1       |     -300.0      |
|   2    |       1       |     -300.0      |
+--------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I need to select every company along with the sum of it's total amount of sales and the sum of it's total balance moves

**desired result**

```
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| id |  total_amount_sum    |   balance_move_sum  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| 1  |         700          |          100        |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| 2  |        (null)        |        (null)       |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
```

I tried this SQL query

```
SELECT 
    company.id,
    sum(total_amount) total_amount_sum,
    sum(balance_move) balance_move_sum
FROM company
     LEFT JOIN sales ON company.id = sales.company_id 
     LEFT JOIN moves ON company.id = moves.company_id
GROUP BY company.id
```

But the `sum()` functions add all the redundant values came from the joins which result in `2100 (700*3)` for total amount and `300 (100*3)` for net balance

***bad SQL statement result***

```
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| id |  total_amount_sum    |   balance_move_sum  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| 1  |         2100         |          300        |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| 2  |        (null)        |        (null)       |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve the result I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeating rows by doing your joins.

Company: 1 row per company

After Sales join: 3 rows per company (1x3)

After Moves join: 9 rows per company (3x3)

You end up triplicating your `SUM` because of this.

One way to fix is to use derived tables [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe73a/13/0), which calculate the `SUM` first, then join the resulting rows 1-to-1.

```
SELECT 
    company.id,
    total_amount_sum,
    balance_move_sum
FROM company
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(total_amount) total_amount_sum, company_id
           FROM sales
           GROUP BY company_id
           ) sales ON company.id = sales.company_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(balance_move) balance_move_sum, company_id
           FROM moves
           GROUP BY company_id
           ) moves ON company.id = moves.company_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sub-queries to calculate the two sums separately will work.

```
SELECT 
    company.id,
    (Select sum(total_amount) from sales where sales.company_id = company.id) total_amount_sum,
    (Select sum(balance_move) from moves where moves.company_id = company.id) balance_move_sum
FROM company
```

Comment: thank you very much , it works , I have a question : Is this query going to call the sub queries for every record in the company table?

Comment: I mean for each record , If i have 30 rows in the company table, the subquery is going to be executed 30 times ?

Comment: Databases don't quite work like that, it will be optimised to some extent, but yes, this way could have performance problems.  Best to try both and see what happens!